# java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.apache.phoenix.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation using pheonix in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I am trying to write a Spark dataframe to HBase using pheonix and I see the following error. Any idea what is going on here ? :

An error occurred while calling o102.save.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/BaseRelation;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/sifsuser/appcache/application_1569479196412_0065/container_e06_1569479196412_0065_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 593, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/sifsuser/appcache/application_1569479196412_0065/container_e06_1569479196412_0065_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/sifsuser/appcache/application_1569479196412_0065/container_e06_1569479196412_0065_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/sifsuser/appcache/application_1569479196412_0065/container_e06_1569479196412_0065_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o102.save.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/BaseRelation;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

question is quite old but I face same issue so maybe it's worth answering.

In my case the issue was that I had insufficient conf in spark submit for

> spark.driver.extraClassPath

and

> spark.executor.extraClassPath

when I add

```
    --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=phoenix-spark2.jar:phoenix-client.jar:/etc/hbase/conf"
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=phoenix-spark2.jar:phoenix-client.jar:/etc/hbase/conf"
```

it's works for me (versions: phoenix 4.7, hbase 1.1 and hartonworks hdp 2.6.5)